# .NET Core global tools don’t work in Azure Cloud Shell

Tags: azure, powershell, .net-core, azure-cloud-shell

I installed a .NET global tool in Azure Cloud Shell (dotnet tool install -g). The installation works without reporting any problems.

After the installation the shell can’t find the tool (The term '{toolname}' is not recognized as the name of…).

Restarting the Cloud Shell shows no effect. I can see the tool with ‘dotnet tool list -g’. I can install and use the tool as local tool.

Is this a bug or a Cloud Shell restriction or am I missing something?

Comment: Which tool did you try to install?

Comment: @BhargaviAnnadevara-MSFT: It is a custom tool. Thanks for responding. But as you can see in my answer, I already solved my problem.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out. Similar issues are listed out in the Troubleshooting doc as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/troubleshoot-usage-issues#executable-file-not-found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question:

dotnet-tools doesn’t update the PATH environment variable like it does under Windows. I fixed this by adding the following line to my profile.ps1:

```
$Env:PATH += ":$HOME/.dotnet/tools"
```

profile.ps1 is located under $HOME/.config/PowerShell. If this is a new Cloud Shell installation, this file and folder must first be created.